# UIPageControl with Images in Xcode 5/iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uipagecontrol

I've been searching for an hour now and can't seem to find out how to use UIPageControl to act as a swipe between images (sort of like the weather application, but with images instead of pages).

I have 7 images and I want to use them to create an instruction manual for a game I'm developing.
I am new to developing so bear with me.

Can anyone provide links to tutorials that will show me this, or show me the code in the comments below?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) tutorial, check the **Paging with UIScrollView** section

You can use `UIPageViwController` to do something similar. [Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) is the tutorial for it.